# Apache CXF and Spring dependencies conflict exception

Tags: spring, maven, cxf

I want to integrate CXF and Spring for a simple JAX-WS. Below is the maven pom file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run the jetty using maven command. It had some exception like this:

```
spring java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.converter.ConverterRegistry.addConverter(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter;)V
```

It seems the problem is CXF and Spring dependencies problems. When I go to the target folders and find out there are two version of Spring with the version I specified and the version CXF depend on. 3.0.7?

If I change the spring version to the lower one and it works.

I just wondering are there any way to solve this if I still want to use the latest version of Spring?

Comment: there are two version of Spring with the version ?? what this means ??

Comment: In the target folder generated by maven, there are 3.0.7 version of spring and 3.2.3 version of spring. One by CXF and the other specified by myself. understand?

Answer (score 0):

I think I find out the reason. I need also to put spring-core as maven dependency. Because the converter in the exception are in the core dependency.

So when the maven jetty run, there are two version of spring, spring-core is using 3.0.7 which is with CXF, and the other are 3.2.3 which is I specified.

I need to keep consistent with spring version in the project.